# Enable Checking in Syntastic

Tags: vim, syntastic

How would I do it? I've been reading around and I cannot figure it out. Let's say I want to enable syntax checking for C++. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

After Installing Syntastic using pathogen or your favorite plugin manager,
By default it will give you highlight the line numbers about error messages.
If not, may be the file might not be detected as correct file type.
Please set the file type to CPP. using the following ex command.

```
:set ft=cpp
```

General behaviour is that the error messages will show up after we save the buffer using `:w`

If you want to manually view the error message suggestions later at any point of time, Use the following command

```
:SyntasticCheck
```

More about the global commands of syntastic can be found in help documentation using the following command.

```
:h syntastic
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Even after doing all that, nothing... I remember that running a command earlier said I had no available checkers or something...

Comment: @user3682802, well… syntastic is only a frontend for [external programs](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Syntax-Checkers): it doesn't do any checking by itself.

Comment: Try `:SyntasticInfo` and what's the output? Then check the wiki and install the external programs as required.